# Animating a missile in HTML5/WinJS

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

I'm writing a game using HTML5/WinJS on Windows 8.  I'm trying to produce the effect of a bullet or missile firing at something; however, I can't seem to get the object to go through another image in the background without trailing a border.  My working theory is that the border I'm seeing is caused by using `clearRect`.  Here's my code:

```
var moveBullet = function(missile) {

    if (missile.Image == undefined || missile.Image == null) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = "/images/missileImg.png";
        image.onload = function () {
            canvasContext.clearRect(missile.PointX - (image.width / 2), missile.PointY, image.width, image.height);
            missile.PointY += BULLET_SPEED;
            canvasContext.drawImage(image, missile.PointX - (image.width / 2), missile.PointY);
        };
    } else {
        canvasContext.clearRect(missile.PointX - (missile.Image.width / 2), missile.PointY, missile.Image.width, missile.Image.height);
        missile.PointY += BULLET_SPEED;
        canvasContext.drawImage(missile.Image, missile.PointX - (missile.Image.width / 2), missile.PointY);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect without using clearRect, or a more efficient way of restoring the background as it moves past?

Comment: What do you mean by "trailing a border"?

Comment: As it passes past another image, you can see a small black border surrounding it.

Comment: did you check if is fully transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your clearRect area a few pixels larger than the missile image. Drawing on a canvas in general has some built-in anti-aliasing. This means that if you draw a line with one color, then draw the same line with the background color, you'll not remove the original line. Something similar might be happening here, in which case a few extra pixels should help.

That said, there's a caveat to be aware of here.

First, I assume the background is separate element from the canvas? It looks like it as you're not redrawing that part on the canvas itself.

The reason I ask is that making repeated calls to clearRect on the same canvas will eventually show performance problems. What happens is that every call to clearRect accumulates into a complex region within the canvas--essentially its transparency mask. So every time the canvas has to be rendered, which happens any time you change it, it has to process that transparent area. Gradually, as you leave more and more small clearRect trails across the canvas, this region will become more and more complex and performance will drop.

I did this experiment with the Blizzard demo on the IE Test Drive site once, where I wondered why the demo was clearing the entire canvas with every animation frame. So I tried just clearing the trail behind each snowflake (and made each one a little bigger as I suggest above, because I had trails). Seemed like the right thing to do, but the performance plummeted by several orders of magnitude. Asking around within the IE team, they confirmed the region behavior I describe.

So the best thing to do, actually, is to do a clearRect on the *entire* canvas with every frame, then redraw the missile and any other bits that you're animating. This may seem counter intuitive, but ends up working best and avoids all these glitches with pixel trails.

Comment: When I read this, I thought clearing the screen each time would cause a flickering effect, but it's much smoother - thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought so too. But drawing to a canvas doesn't mean you're drawing directly to the screen. Everything on the canvas is buffered until the next refresh to the screen, at which time the contents of the whole element are drawn all at once. In other words, drawing to a canvas is not the same as drawing to a window, so the concern about flicker isn't the same.